# jQuery Mobile dropdown (Custom Select Menus)not opening working with Marionette

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile, backbone.js, marionette

I am trying to use jQuery Mobile **Select Menus** with Marionette and the dropdown opens perfectly, but when I try to use **Custom Select Menus** for rich UI using

```
data-native-menu="false"
```

attribute or using

```
$(document).bind('mobileinit',function(){
  $.mobile.selectmenu.prototype.options.nativeMenu = false;
});
```

the drop down never opens, the link changes to a # reference but the dropdown is not visible.

I would like the custom select menu look, I don't want the default one. Is the issue with jQuery Mobile or using it with Marionette?

Answer (score 0):

Funny how this issue have been my headache since yesterday.. Works in IE, not in Chrome og FF.